# Is there a way to override the server configuration 'statement_timeout' on Azure DB for PostgreSQL?

Tags: npgsql, azure-postgresql

In the Azure Portal under PostgreSQL the server configuration statement_timeout controls the following.

> "Sets the maximum allowed duration (in milliseconds) of any statement.
>   0 turns this off."

There doesn't seem to be a way to override that setting once it is set. We use Npgsql's .NET Provider and have tried setting the timeout=0 and the command timeout=0 on the connection string to see that would override but it doesn't seem to have an effect on the timeout. We don't want to disable it or set it to a large interval, but we have some stored procedures that run a long time and would like to set on a per statement basis.

thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can set statement_timeout at a transaction level. In the example below, I start a transaction, set the timeout, call postgres' sleep function, then mark the end of the transaction.

```
BEGIN; SET LOCAL statement_timeout = 2000; SELECT pg_sleep(3); COMMIT;
```

Note that because the sleep function times out (which is marked as an `ERROR`), the transaction is rolled back.

Alternatively, you can set statement_timeout at a session level using just `SET`.

Info about `SET` and `SET LOCAL`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-set.html

Comment: I'll give this a try and get back.